# How to display the process id that opened a particular socket within a docker container?

Tags: sockets, docker

I installed docker 1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 and from a container I can do `ps -eaf` to display the list of processes within the container

But when using `ss -lap` or `nestat - lp` I cannot get the PID of the processes that opened particular ports. Is there a way to get around this in order to know which PID opened a particular port within the container?

Answer (score 1):

if you have lsof and want to see who opened the port 8000, then `lsof -i :8000` should show it

Comment: the following command shows `$ lsof -i :8000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  32279   gg    3u  IPv4 1712775      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
` so I see the pid 32279 has opened the port 8000, it seems to provides an answer to the question